# JOLT filter array elements based on existence of a key field

Tags: arrays, filter, key, jolt

Is it possible to filter array elements based on presence of a field.

My input JSON is as below:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "logical": {
      "schemas": [
        {
          "name": "myschema",
          "tables": [
            {
              "name": "myname",
              "alias": "temp_alias",
              "keys": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "key": "key1",
                  "match": "match_val"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "key": "key2",
                  "match": "match_val"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "key": "key3"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "key": "key4"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output is:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "logical": {
      "schemas": [
        {
          "tables": [
            {
              "name": "myname",
              "alias": "temp_alias",
              "keys": {
                "name": "value1",
                "match": "match_val",
                "key": [
                  "key1",
                  "key2"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If there is "match" field in "keys" element, then we will take "key" value from that element and put in the output array "key".

I am using this spec file, but not getting required output. Can anyone please suggest how to do it?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "payload": {
        "*": "&",
        "logical": {
          "schemas": {
            "*": {
              "tables": {
                "*": {
                  "name": "payload.logical.schemas[&3].tables[&1].name",
                  "alias": "payload.logical.schemas[&3].tables[&1].alias",
                  "keys": {
                    "*": {
                      "match": {
                        "match1|match2": {
                          "@2": {
                            "name": "payload.logical.schemas[&4].tables[&4].keys.name",
                            "match": "payload.logical.schemas[&4].tables[&4].keys.match",
                            "key": "payload.logical.schemas[&4].tables[&4].keys.key"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got desired output with below spec file:

`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "payload": {
        "*": "&",
        "logical": {
          "schemas": {
            "*": {
              "tables": {
                "*": {
                  "name": "payload.logical.schemas[&3].tables[&1].name",
                  "alias": "payload.logical.schemas[&3].tables[&1].alias",
                  "keys": {
                    "*": {
                      "match": {
                        "*": {
                          "@(2,name)": "payload.logical.schemas[&7].tables[&5].keys[&3].name",
                          "@(2,match)": "payload.logical.schemas[&7].tables[&5].keys[&3].match",
                          "@(2,key)": "payload.logical.schemas[&7].tables[&5].keys[&3].key"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "payload": {
        "*": "&",
        "logical": {
          "schemas": {
            "*": {
              "tables": {
                "*": {
                  "name": "payload.logical.schemas[&3].tables[&1].name",
                  "alias": "payload.logical.schemas[&3].tables[&1].alias",
                  "keys": {
                    "*": {
                      "name": "payload.logical.schemas[&5].tables[&3].keys.name",
                      "match": "payload.logical.schemas[&5].tables[&3].keys.match",
                      "key": "payload.logical.schemas[&5].tables[&3].keys.key"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "logical": {
          "schemas": {
            "*": {
              "tables": {
                "*": {
                  "keys": {
                    "name": "ONE",
                    "match": "ONE"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`